# Detect if free app has been purchased for money

Tags: android, google-play

We are planning on changing our currently paid app, into a "free" (demo) app with in-app purchase to unlock the full game.

Our problem with making this transition is that we already have customers who've paid for the app. We therefore need to ensure that they wont have to pay for something they've already bought once. We have looked for every possible solution we can think of, but without luck.

Licensing is out of the question, as it will always return valid for free apps.

Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated. As a fallback we'll have to create two apps, but we would much rather prefer to only keep a single one.

Regards
Jannek

Edit:

Thanks for the feedback. We didn't find a solution, but ended up using the first achievement to unlock the game by default. this covers 80% of our players. Unfortunately also 80% of the pirates. for the remaining 20% we setup a token server, where they can unlock the game by entering the last 8 digits from their purchase info.

This also allows us to give out promo codes on Google Play.

Comment: Why don't you make a server that keeps track of everyone using your purchased app, then release the free?

Comment: Lots of applications have two versions or more with free and paid version. The users that already paid, update their app through the paid one, and the free users keep the free with unlocked feature. The free version should anyway have a different rating since this can also be useful for you to check if the free release was actually worth it. Also It won't hurt in any way the already paid version ratings.

Answer (score 2):

A couple of unsatisfying solutions:

1. Update the app before you make it free. Collect IDs somehow of people who use it and record them. Downside is it will miss people that rarely update or use your app.
2. Release the paid app as a new package. Convert the old one into a "pre-paid licence". You can detect whether the licence app is installed or not from the new one. Downside is you lose all your ratings and reviews.